# What Am I Doing Wrong Opening This File?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am trying to open this file, but for some reason, it just won't. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. From everything I have read online, it seems like everything is right.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


int main()
{
    std::string accnts_file = "accnt_info.txt";
    int accnt_counter = 0;
    std::string strLine;
    std::string strData;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > accnts;
    std::ifstream ifs( accnts_file.c_str(), std::ifstream::in );

    if( !ifs )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file"
                  << std::endl;
    }

    while( ifs.good() )
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Any help would really be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure that the file you want to load exists in the same directory as the executable.

File paths in executables are interpreted as relative to the executable, if not absolute.
If the file paths in the executable were relative to the source files that the exe was generated from, that would be a huge mess when it comes to large programs with thousands of source files.
Also, the source files only exist on the network of the developers, so any home user would find his program searching for ridiculous paths that don't exist on his machine.

> File paths are relative to the executable's directory, if not absolute. File paths are interpreted entirely new at every execution, because memory constantly changes.

Comment: Thank you. That's what i had tried to do, but it wouldn't let me for a couple of days.